# When is it not a good idea to create a class?

Tags: c++

I have a question related to C++ design. What are some criteria that you use when deciding if you should create a class? In theory, you can put anything (except the main function) in a class - but I am slowly learning that perhaps this approach is not the best one. So - when do you think you should not create a class, and why?

Comment: Very subjective. Likely to get closed. but my answer... Don't make a class when it can't be described easily as an object.

Comment: What do you mean by "create"? Define? Instantiate?

Comment: Single responsibility: Make one thing to perform one task. That thing can be a function, a class or a template, whichever is most appropriate.

Comment: I actually mean declare and define.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a general rule, create a class whenever you have a data structure and that data structure has a particular set of operations that will (mostly) use the structure.

Answer (score 2):

Create a class when you have some data that have some operations working on them. If you find yourself having one file with some static global data and some functions using them, you are most likely better off using a class for that. It is true that you may only need one instance of the class, which then basically is the same as a file with globals/functions, but you never know if you ever need to have more instances of it. I've had many personal experiences where this happened!

Don't force everything into classes though. Somethings are just not classes. For example math functions. They are just functions that operate on their input and produce output and they don't have any state. An example of force-feeding math functions in classes is in Java where there is a Math class full of static functions! It's just utterly stupid. (Yeah yeah, I know, Java cannot have anything outside classes because it force-feeds everything in classes by design!! BY DESIGN!)

Anyway, some things are very obvious. For example a class for "big numbers" plus a lot of operator overloadings, OO stuff (obviously), enhanced data structures that are self constructing/destructing etc.

Some may not be that obvious. Take for example a random generator. On one hand, you may argue that it has a seed that needs to be stored and `rand()` operates on that, so it should be put in a class. This makes sense. Yet, you may also say all the program uses the same `rand()`, you don't need 2 instances of it and if you create an object for it, you have to keep passing it around everyone which is not worth it. In such cases, you have to decide whether to make a class out of it or not based on your program itself.

Comment: Great example with rand() of the factors that can influence the decision.

Comment: Yes, good point. That's actually exactly what prompted me to ask this question in the first place - in my program, I ended up putting a lot of stuff inside classes which I made into singletons for this exact reason.

Comment: You know, when all the heat of classes and OO was out there, some people came with the idea of singletons: "Look! I can have the exact same thing with globals/functions but with classes! I'm so OO. I'm great and I'm proud of myself" Then some OO-fanatics started using it: "Man this is awesome! I don't need to write anything outside classes every again!" Then they realized what a stupid idea it was and now it's an [antipattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Answer (score 1):

There are no rigid rules (other than perhaps those you'll find in textbooks or at lectures by "experts"), but basically you might define a new class for one of two reasons:

1. You've got a collection of data and procedures which present a new external behavior.
2. You've got a new internal representation for a given external behavior.

The first case is essentially defining an entirely new class (though it may be a subclass of a relatively generic class), while the second is defining a new subclass of some superclass which largely describes its external behavior.

Do be a little wary of going "class crazy".  C++ has ordinary structures as well as classes (though technically the difference is only whether the members default to public vs private), and some things (eg, parameter lists, or simple internal structures) are probably better left as simple structs, without making all data members private and requiring setters and getters, etc.  (Java and some others have no struct concept, so everything must be defined as a class, regardless.)